# Using concat inside mergeMap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have a hard time understanding something related to using a [`concat`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat) function inside a [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) operator.

The documentation for `concat` says that

> You can pass either an array of Observables, or put them directly as arguments.

When I put the Observables directly as arguments, like in the following example, I correctly get 20 and 24 in the console.

```
of(4)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(number => concat(of(5 * number), of(6 * number)))
  )
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

But when I put them as an array, then in the console I get the Observables and not their values:

```
of(4)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(number => concat([of(5 * number), of(6 * number)]))
  )
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Here's a [live version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hce1cn) in Stackblitz.

Any idea why is that? Shouldn't both examples work identically?

Comment: This is most likely a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: however you can use `concat(...[o1, o2])`

Comment: or send the Observables directly like in the first example.

Comment: However, I don't think there's a mistake in the documentation because the signature suggests that arrays are accepted.
`concat<T, R>(...observables: Array<ObservableInput<any> | SchedulerLike>): Observable<R>`

Comment: `Array` is required when you use `...rest` syntax

Comment: Then it's definitely a mistake. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two scenarios are different and they should not work identically. `concat` takes Observables as arguments and it will sequentially subscribe to those streams and only subscribe to the next Observable when the previous one completed. Every operator or creation method returns an Observable. This means that in the first example, when you are using `concat`, it will return an Observable that emits `20` and then `24`. Because you are dealing with a nested Observable you have to use `mergeMap` which will subscribe to the resulting Observable returned by `concat`.

Now in the second example, if you pass in an array, `concat` will convert this (using `from()` internally) to an Observable that emits 2 values, and those values are Observables again. So you have 3 levels of nesting here. The first is the most outer Observable, the source, which `of(4)`, the second level is the one you map to inside your `mergeMap` and the third in the second example are the Observables inside your array. The thing is you only flatten the levels up to level 2 but not the 3rd level. Again, in your second example the Observable returned by `mergeMap` emits two Observables but those are just the proxies and not the values emitted by these Observables. If you want to subscribe to those as well, you could chain on another `mergeMap` like so

```
concatArray() {
  of(4)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(number => concat([of(5 * number), of(6 * number)])),
      mergeMap(x => x)
    )
    .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
}
```

Another way is to **spread** the array so that `concat` does not receive an object that is `ArrayLike` but rather Observables directly:

```
concatArray() {
  of(4)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(number => concat(...[of(5 * number), of(6 * number)]))
    )
    .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
}
```

Both will print out:

```
20
24
```

I hope this makes this a little bit more clear and describes the differences between the first and the second example.

Comment: This explanation makes it extremely clear. Thanks a lot!

Spreading the array is also pretty much what @martin suggested.

So what I can conclude from this is that the documentation for `concat` is definitely wrong. One of the examples there [Concatenate an array of 3 Observables](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat#concatenate-an-array-of-3-observables) is passing an array. That's why I was thinking that both of my examples should be identical. And the description itself suggests that arrays can be passed. This should be fixed.

Thanks once again!

Comment: You're welcome! And yes, this should be corrected in the docs. It will not print out the values of those timers but rather just console log the Observable object. But you would have to subscribe to those Observables to get the values emitted or spread the array.